# CompletableFuture in Spring MVC

Tags: java, completable-future

I am considering using `CompletableFuture` to start processing something on the database. The operation will take a few seconds but I want to return control back to the browser without waiting for this to complete.

My question: Is this safe? Is there a risk that my `Asynchronous` task will get garbage collected because the initial request has returned a response?

Comment: No, there is no risk. The task (`Function` or `Runnable` or whatever) is reachable by a thread, so it won't be garbage collected.

Answer (score 1):

You may get the below exception when the request is done and the completable future thread is still running. Especially, I have seen this error while trying to get data from database as the database bean was defined with aop scoped proxy (session).

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found:

**Workaround solution:-**

Invoked another RESTFul service to run the task in new request

```
SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor taskExecutor = new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor();
CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> callRestFulService(Integer.valueOf(id)),
                taskExecutor);
```

**Note:-**

I have just shared my experience. There could be other ways to handle this scenario or if you don't have any database interactions, it may work as well.